# How do RSA keep Authentication and Non-repudiation

Tags: encryption, rsa

Sorry for my bad English. I have read about Security and understood how RSA work.
But how can RSA keep Authentication, a man in middle can use public key and fake message back. And how it keep Non-repudiation, someone who send you a message encrypted by public key can say that it is not from him and it is faked?

Comment: RSA alone can't prevent man-in-the-middle, that's what certificates are used for. And for non-repudiation the sender creates a signature with his _private_ key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [some math behind](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)) RSA PKI (public key infrastructure) but I will try to keep it simple. Though this scenario is described in many other sites and questions/answers. What exacly you don't understand?

The idea is, that it is easy to encrypt with the public key, but not possible to decrypt. The decryption is possible only with the private key.

Seems your question is aiming somewhere else. What you are missing (and is not part of the RSA itself) are [certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509). Certificates may use RSA. A certificate is information about a holder of the public key. Still - there is a problem. If an entity (person, website) provides you a certificate, how can you be sure the cretificate really belongs to the website, person or organization?

That's why there is defined term **Certificate Authority** (CA) - there are organizations which you (or your browser) should trust.

So when a website creates its RSA keypair, some certificate authority issues a signed certificate (bound to the public key) that the certificate is really from the website, person or organization.

> a man in middle can you public key and fake message back.

Your client (browser, application) must have a list of trusted Certificate Authorities. Usually it is already stored in your system. So the real web page can provide its public key and certificate and use encryption based on the public key. The browser checks that the certificate is valid and it is issued by a trusted authority.

The "man in the middle" would not be able to provide valid and trusted (signed by CA) certificate.

> And how it keep Non-repudiation, someone who send you a
>   message encrypted by public key can say that it is not 
>   from him and it is faked?

The same comes to the signing. Once data are signed (or authenticated) using the private key, the signature can be validated by anyone using the public key. A certificate is bound to the public key.  Usualy the signing certificate is issued only when identity is verified by the certificate authority (for example for electronic ID cards, code signing certificates, ..). So anyone could verify the signature was created by someone who was verified by a trusted authority.